# Ubuntu File Permsissions

Tags: permissions

I created three users bob, alice and eve and added them to groups defend, attack and evil respectively. Eve should not be able to read or write any file not created by her but bob and alice should be able to read not write files created by two of them. i gave the files craeted by alice and bob a permission of 644 but they are still unbale to cat the files but when i vi the files i was not able to write to it but i could read but eve could still access the file. Does any one have any suggestins

Comment: Which distro and version of Linux are you using?

Comment: 644 mean _everybody_ could read the file. Which includes open them in and editor.
Every user has by default it's own group so creating another group with the same permission doesn't make too much sense.
Except that, the permission of the directory where the file is placed may matter.

Comment: I am using ubuntu with no GUI in orcale Virtual box I was accessed to create three groups and modify persmissons as such

Comment: Who are you: (there is a user involved speaking with the pronoun "I" in your text) ... How does that user relate in that permissions riddle? Is that some sort of student test/homework?

Comment: Please edit your question and describe as detailed and clear as possible what the intention is and what the expected outcome should be. Currently it is very vague and based on the question so far doesn't really make sense.